# Configuring synonym analyzer for lucene

Tags: content-search, lucene

My question is related to sitecore search / content search, which is a topic I'm not fully experienced with, so don't hesitate to correct me :)
We just want to use the default Lucene indexer with a synonym analyzer. I have written following into the config in hopes that it would enable synonym searches.

```
<contentSearch>
  <indexConfigurations>
    <defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
      <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.PerExecutionContextAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="defaultAnalyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.DefaultPerFieldAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          <param desc="defaultAnalyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.SynonymAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param hint="engine" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.XmlSynonymEngine, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
              <param hint="xmlSynonymFilePath">~\App_Data\Synonyms\synonyms.xml</param>
            </param>
          </param>
        </param>
      </analyzer>
    </defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
  </indexConfigurations>
</contentSearch>
```

In the synonym xml file I have a group with MacA and MacB, however when I make a search with MacB I do not get the same results as with MacA (just for testing purposes)
Can anyone here spot where I made a mistake in the config? I have also tried with the fully descirptive path to the xml file which still didn't work.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<synonyms>
  <group>
    <syn>fast</syn>
    <syn>quick</syn>
    <syn>rapid</syn>
  </group>
  <group>
    <syn>slow</syn>
    <syn>decrease</syn>
  </group>
  <group>
    <syn>google</syn>
    <syn>search</syn>
  </group>
  <group>
    <syn>check</syn>
    <syn>lookup</syn>
    <syn>look</syn>
    <syn>MacB</syn>
    <syn>MacA</syn>
    <syn>MacAllan</syn>
  </group>
</synonyms>
```

Comment: hello. How are you performing the search? Could you provide a query?

Comment: @VadimBirkos the query is constructed with an IProviderSearchContext ex: var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>(). Where the context/index is fetched from a ICommerceSearchManager. I ofcourse do some filters and sorting. In the end I fetch the results by query.Get(Results).

Comment: I meant part of the query where you search by term. Do you use equals or contains?

Comment: @VadimBirkos as in a raw SQL query format?

Comment: I meant the Search query that contains in the Search log file. Or code example that performing search.